# Failed to find jdk

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am trying to install android sdk, but I am having a problem. First, I have installed java (JDK) 7u5 and then I tried to install android sdk 20.exe then I got the below error. How can I fix that problem ?

[image: The error]

Comment: First, find out where you have JAVA folder on your machine. Second, make sure it has JDK also not just JRE. Third, create environment variable--Computer right click--> properties--->Advanced settings --create JAVA_HOME varaible and set the JAVA folder path there.

Comment: I tried it, but I got same error. Do I need to restart the computer ?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin"

Comment: Don't point till bin. Remove bin from the path.

Comment: Posted as answer. If helped you. Please accept as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, find out where you have JAVA folder on your machine.
- Second, make sure it has JDK also not just JRE.
- Third, create environment variable--Computer right click--> properties--->Advanced settings   --create JAVA_HOME varaible and set the JAVA folder path there. Make sure bin folder is not included in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

After Installing JDK you have to set the path in eclipse as to where you JDK exists. Please go through these steps:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html